# IOS Dismiss/Show keyboard without Resigning First Responder

Tags: ios, keyboard

My application is used with a barcode scanner connected via Bluetooth.  When the scanner is connected you can double tap a button on the scanner to dismiss/show the on screen keyboard.  90% of the time the user will want the keyboard to be hidden as they will be scanning a barcode to input data.  There are a few exceptions that I know of ahead of time that the keyboard will need to be enabled,  I would like to save them the effort of pressing the scanner button to bring up the keyboard and instead force the keyboard to show up.

The scanner does not use resignfirstresponder to dismiss the keyboard, this is evident because the cursor is still visible and scanning a barcode will input data into the current text field.

Does anyone know how to dismiss/show the on screen keyboard without using resignfirstresponder?

For reference I am using this scanner http://ww1.socketmobile.com/products/bluetooth-scanners/how-to-buy/details.aspx?sku=CX2864-1336

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still struggling with this, you can achieve this in Swift by making the inputView of the textfield equals `UIView()`

That is:

```
yourtextfield.inputview = UIView()
```

Answer (score 2):

To end editing completely in the view you can use the following

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

This will remove the keyboard for you in the view.

Comment: It does remove the keyboard but it does not address the heart of the question.  The idea is to remove or show the keyboard without changing the ability to enter text via the scanner.  If the endEditing command is used it will remove the cursor from the active text field.

Comment: It work for normal textfields keyboards. But can not move keyboard by present system SMS controller

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today and have found a solution. The trick is to use a secondary text field that is off-screen or hidden with a custom empty `inputView` set and make that field become the first responder. That field captures text from the hardware scanner while the software keyboard hides.

However I got this working using a very similar approach and instead making the view controller itself the first responder as the scanning input view.

Example:

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UIKeyInput {

    let searchField = UITextField()
    let softwareKeyboardHider = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(searchField)
        inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
        inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var inputView: UIView? {
        return softwareKeyboardHider
    }

    var hasText: Bool {
        return searchField.hasText
    }

    func insertText(_ text: String) {
        searchField.insertText(text)
    }

    func deleteBackward() {
        searchField.deleteBackward()
    }
}
```

Now, when you want to hide the software keyboard make `SearchViewController` the first responder.

To show the software keyboard make `SearchViewController.searchField` the first responder.