# Hide textField keyboard without resigning first responder

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

I would have been confident that I could have found this answer elsewhere, but I have researched extensively without finding a suitable answer.

I am trying to hide the keyboard on hitting the "return" key, however, I need the textField to remain being the first responder. I tried by utilizing textField.endEditing(true), but this does makes the TF resign first responder.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you NOT want to resign first responder? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It sounds like you have an X/Y problem, or a lack of understanding of how the UIResponder chain works.  Check the linked duplicates.

Comment: Or better yet, this one: [IOS Dismiss/Show keyboard without Resigning First Responder](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18963385/2415822)